# MVC Set tempdata when user clicks on actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

Is it possible?

I tried:

```
@Html.ActionLink("linktext", "Index", "Home", null, new { @TempData["variablehere"] = "texthere"; })
```

But did not work..

Comment: This is not possible, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's not possible because TempData is a server-side function, and when the user clicks on something it happens on the browser client-side.  You have to post back to the server in order to set something in TempData.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, but you can pass value in query string. Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string valueToBePassed)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "Index", "Home", new { valueToBePassed = "ABCDEF" }, null)
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not how I want to do it, thanks again tho!

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

Your action Result:

```
public ActionResult Index(string valueToBePassed)
{
   TempData["valuetopass"]=valueToBePassed;    // if need use .ToString();
   TempData.Keep();

    return View();
}
```

---

This is your View any.cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("linktext", "Index", "Home", null, new {@valueToBePassed= @TempData["valuetopass"] })
```

---

You can see the result in your linked view using this assign

```
<p>@TempData[valuetopass]</p>
```

That's it. Try this